# find files by number with leading zero's via regex

Tags: regex

I have 22 files file001 - file022, I would like to use regex to find grab only file005-file022.

I know that `00[5-9]` grabs 005-009 and `0[12][0-9]` grabs 010-022.

I am having problems putting them together into one regex.

Comment: Which language are you planning to use for this regex?  C, C++, C#, Java, PHP, Perl, Python, ... Or are you planning to write a Unix shell script?  And if a script, which tools are you planning to use?  You've not yet specified your context sufficiently accurately for much of an answer to be possible.  We can offer guesses, but that's all.  (Note, too, that your `0[12][0-9]` pattern would match files 023..029 which you imply you don't want. It works OK when those files don't exist, of course, but is not robust.)

Comment: Very good point @JonathanLeffler.  The problem is where I need it is a "Regex" capable field inside a Java Program.  (Kettle to be exact), so I'm not sure I could answer your questions with complete confidence.  What I needed was helping on the grouping, and DocMax got me where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most-readable way would be `(00[5-9]|0[12][0-9])` but a more compact way is `0(0[5-9]|[12][0-9])`. Or, depending on your regex engine, `0(0[5-9]|[12]\d)`.

If the engine supports it, a non-capturing group is preferred for the "either or" as `0(?:0[5-9]|[12]\d)`, assuming you do not need to separately capture the last two digits.

Answer (score 0):

Since the context is not clear so far and combining two regular expressions might hurt readability, I would propose an alternative:

```
    List<String> filenames = new ArrayList<String>();
    String filename = "file007";
    int fileIndex = Integer.parseInt(filename.substring(5, 7));
    if (fileIndex > 4 && fileIndex < 23) {
        filenames.add(filename);
    }
```

Hopefully the Java code is self-explanatory.